# Moving linux in a hard drive to an ssd

Tags: arch-linux, filesystems, windows

How would I go about moving my linux system (arch), to another drive previously containing windows (ntfs file sistem). Im deciding to move because I installed arch in a super slow hd and now want to change it to my main ssd. I was also wondering if I need to tweak any configs inside my system, as the ssd is a little bit smaller than the hd, and I generated my fstab file using the hard drive uuid. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not know Arch, I use Ubuntu. But standard suggestion is a new clean install & restore from your normal backup. Become a good time to prove that backup is complete as if you are not able to restore it, then it is not a working backup.  You still have HDD to add any missing info, if required. You cannot reboot with both drives connected if you use same UUIDs are duplicates are not allowed.

Comment: @oldfred What do I backup outside of my home folder and pacman packages?

Comment: Not sure with Arch or your configuration. Do you have server type apps installed in/ / (root) like database or web? Some suggest saving /etc, but not automatically restoring if not exactly same version. I manually edit several grub files in / and just copy those or any other files I manually edit into /home, so backed up with my /home backup. What to backup TheFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2456011 But Arch may be somewhat different.

Comment: @oldfred thx, your first answer worked out pretty well . I just had to follow arch wiki's page on moving to new hardware, and to update some files (such as fstab and grub.cfg). And also backed up /etc/ too since most files for my display manager, cli applications and other configs reside there. But it was pretty easy at the end, I just had to pay special attention to the fstab and grub files (re-generating them). Thanks again for answering my post, God bless.